# Postgresql cannot connect to server

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

The project is a django web app, packed on docker containers. For some reason, I cannot run the server and launch it.

when I run "manage.py runserver", this error occurs:

```
File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "158.160.17.21", port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

What do you think can be done with it? Thank you.

Comment: provide docker-compose file

Comment: Few possibilities... 
1. The PostgreSQL database server is not up or online. 
2. The PostgreSQL database is not accepting requests from your machine/code (in this case you may need to change the database config file to allow connections from public internet). 
3. There is something blocking your code from accessing the database server, such as firewall, port whitelisting/blacklisting etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your error tells me that you're using a locally installed copy of `psycopg2`, a Python client library for PostgreSQL, to connect to the database. This is happening behind the scenes when Django needs to make that connection, but it's interesting that it's installed locally, rather than in a docker container, given you said your Django webapp is running in Docker.

The third line of your error is very simple: it tells you that

1. the programme is expecting Postgres to be served on a machine with the IP address `158.160.17.21` on port `5432` (the default port for Postgres)
2. it isn't there

Now, this IP address is not a default and doesn't refer to your own machine, so it must be something you've provided. An IP lookup suggests it's in Venezuela (does that sound right to you?). Perhaps you *are* expecting Postgres to be served on a third party machine; if so, you'll need to check that you have the right IP address and that Postgres is being served there.

Otherwise, you'll need to reconfigure Django to seek Postgres elsewhere.

Comment: This is the project: [ https://github.com/Andrew7567/yamdb_final ]. docker-compose is in the "infra" directory

Comment: Right, but that doesn't actually help me to help you very much, because your docker-compose just refers to a .env file that has been .gitignore-d (excluded from the repo). You should take a look at the .env file and see what the values of the postgres configuration variables are, especially the host name or connection string (depending on how you set it up).

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Manager > Services tab > Right-Click on Mongo > Start.
Now go re-run the server again.